# How to format hreflang from "en-ae" to "en-AE" (WordPress+Rank Math+WPMLl)?

Tags: wordpress, seo, wpml

I need to set it by the technical task.
I've found only

```
function hrefs_to_uppercase($hrefs) {  
    $hrefs = array_change_key_case($hrefs,CASE_UPPER);
    return $hrefs;
}
add_filter( 'wpml_hreflangs', 'hrefs_to_uppercase' );
```

But it makes all characters uppercase - "EN-AE".
Tried manually in wpml settings- didn't help

Comment: why don't you just use `str_replace()`?

Comment: made a mistake somewhere I think and thought that doesn't work with link, not with a. how should I write it correctly? For now I use jquery way, but in php it would be better I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply replace the array key with the following code:

```
function hrefs_to_uppercase($hrefs) {  
    $hrefs['en-AE'] = $hrefs['en-ae'];
    unset($hrefs['en-ae']);
    return $hrefs;
}
add_filter( 'wpml_hreflangs', 'hrefs_to_uppercase' );
```

if you want to make every array key have an uppercase second part (e.g. from `en-us` to `en-US`), you can use the codes below (assumed all your keys have a similar structure like `en-us`):

```
function hrefs_to_uppercase($hrefs) {  
    foreach ($hrefs as $key => $val) {
        $key_tokens = explode('-', $key);
        $new_key = $key_tokens[0] . '-' . strtoupper($key_tokens[1]);
        $hrefs[$new_key] = $hrefs[$key];
        unset($hrefs[$key]);
    }
    return $hrefs;
}
add_filter( 'wpml_hreflangs', 'hrefs_to_uppercase' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved like that for now, maybe right-maybe not

```
     jQuery('[hreflang*="en-ae"]').each(function(){
        // Update the 'rules[0]' part of the name attribute to contain the latest count 
        jQuery(this).attr("hreflang",'en-AE');
    });
```